Stretch Material Design Floating Action Button
Im trying to Stretch Material Design Floating Action Button  "MaterialDesignFloatingActionButton" without success.
the goal is after a task compleet the button will stretch to show info


<Style x:Key="StretchingCircularFAB" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionButton}">
<Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
<Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
 <Setter Property="Template" >
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" >
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Border Name="PART_Border"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        CornerRadius="25" 
                         materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.IsIndicatorVisible="{TemplateBinding materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.IsIndicatorVisible}"
                         materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.IsIndeterminate="{TemplateBinding materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.IsIndeterminate}"

                         >
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter> 

<Button Name="bt_assq"
   materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.IsIndicatorVisible="True"
   materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.IsIndeterminate="True"
    materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.Value="-1"
    Background="Chocolate"
    BorderBrush="Chocolate"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    Style="{StaticResource StretchingCircularFAB}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Pipe" Foreground="#FFFFFF"  
            HorizontalAlignment="left" Width="24" Height="24"
            VerticalAlignment="center"/>
        <TextBlock Text="1223 ms" Name="lb_ertg" Foreground="#FFFFFF" 
            Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTextBlock}"
            FontSize="13" 
            FontWeight ="Bold"
            Margin="5,0,0,0"  
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="center"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>

